# bsub post processing script

Tags: shell, lsf

I was writing a script for submitting parallel jobs in cluster using bsub command

```
while read p; do
  cd $(echo $p | tr -d '\r')
  echo Submitting test: $p
  bsub -P <project> -Jd <job desc> -o lsf.log "sh ./run_test.sh &> $log"
  cd - &> /dev/null
done < $filename
```

How can I compile the results at the end of all test runs?

Comment: Are you talking about the files that are currently saved as `$log`? I would suggest doing this as a post-processing step.

Comment: Yes, Could you help with a small example, I was unable to find one.

Comment: How about doing the post processing in an LSF job. Use job dependency to synchronize them.

Answer (score 0):

How about using something like this?

```
while read p; do
  cd "$(echo "$p" | tr -d '\r')"
  echo "Submitting test: $p"
  bsub -P <project> -Jd <job desc> -o lsf.log \
    "sh ./run_test.sh &> '$log' && cat '$log' >> /path/to/combined/log"
  cd - &> /dev/null
done < "$filename"
```

When each job finishes successfully, the output file is concatenated with the rest.

Comment: the logs are in different folders. I cd into them before i execute bsub command. How would i know if all the jobs are finished is the main problem